# Cache an http call results in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I am new to rails and get stuck on this problem.

The thing I am trying to do is:
I need to call service A to retrieve an idA and then I use idA to perform other actions. my actions in the controller is something like

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def someAction
    idA = getIdAfromServiceA(config)
    doSomethingElseToServiceB(idA)
  end
end
```

Since the result from serviceA only depends on config, once the config is loaded, idA should not change. Therefore I want to cache idA.

I tried to use instance variable to cache it, no luck("getIdAfromServiceA is called is printed" on every request)

```
class SomeController
  def getIdAfromServiceA(config)
    @IdA ||= getIdAfromServiceAviaHTTP(config)
  end

  private
  def getIdAfromServiceAviaHTTP(config)
     puts "getIdAfromServiceAviaHTTP is called"
     #make some http call
  end
end
```

I also tried to put it in `application.rb` to cache it on start up. it shows error: `undefined method 'getIdAfromServiceAviaHTTP' for SomeHelper:Module (NoMethodError)`

```
module MyProject
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.1
    require_relative 'relativePathToSomeHelperModule'
    config.idA  = SomeHelper.getIdAfromServiceAviaHTTP(config)
  end
end
```

So my question is, what's a good way to achieve this ? I've been googling for a while but end up in vain. Could you help me with it ? Thanks !

Comment: Will this `IdA` not change throughout the application?

Comment: yes. it will only change if the user update the config, which requires restart of the application. so it can be treated as constant during the life time of the application

Comment: Then this `idA` is essentially part of config, as I understand you and should be treated as such

Comment: JFYK, method naming and local variables in ruby should be snake_case. You can check other ruby style guide [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Comment: @AtulKhanduri thanks !

Comment: As an aside, it it worthwhile noting that for ever new request, a new instance of `SomeController` (or any other controller) will be created (which is exactly why you see the `puts` statement each time a new request is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a ruby file in under `/config/initializers/` and put that code there.

**Option 1:**

```
# config/initializers/ida_from_api.rb

IDA = SomeHelper.getIdAfromServiceAviaHTTP(config)
```

You can then use `IDA` through out the application.

**Option 2:**

```
# config/initializers/ida_from_api.rb

Rails.configuration.idA = SomeHelper.getIdAfromServiceA(config)
```

You can then use `Rails.configuration.idA` through out the application. Check [Custom configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration) for more details.

FYI - files under `initializers` loaded at the time of application startup.

Comment: Just beat me to it! You can also add `Rails.configuration.idA = SomeHelper.getIdAfromServiceA(config)`, which would then be accessible app-wide via `Rails.configuration.idA`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHeald ! where would you put this line of code ?

Comment: @David Edited my answer to add ChrisHeald's option.